# Good reference to study Free Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I am interested in studying free algebras as Free Pre-Lie Algebras, Free Dendriform Algebras etc. But I dont know what a free algebra is in general. I found this definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) but it does not seem to fit what I read about the free structures that I quoted. Is there a more general definition for free algebras so that these structures are particular cases of it? If so, can anyone indicate me a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For free Lie Lie algebras see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra); a survey on free pre-Lie algebras (also called free left-symmetric algebras) is given in the article [monomial bases of free pre-Lie algebras](http://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/wpapers/s71mahdi.pdf), which has many references, e.g. the book of Reutenauer on free Lie algebras.